# How to get data from $$state object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest, express

$scope.packgs keeps ending up as a $$state object but if I console response it is the correct array of objects I am expecting, what am I doing wrong ?

my controller

```
routerApp.controller('PortalController', ['$scope', '$state', 'UserService', 'PackageService', function($scope, $state, UserService, PackageService) {
$scope.isLoggedIn = UserService.isLoggedIn;
$scope.currentUser = UserService.currentUser;
$scope.logOut = UserService.logOut;

$scope.packgs = PackageService.get($scope.currentUser()).success(function(response){
    return response;
});

/*if($scope.packgs === null){
    $scope.errorMessage = "You are not tracking any packages, add some to your portal!";
}*/
console.log($scope.packgs);
}]);
```

my factory

```
packages.get = function(info){
  return $http.get('/api/packages?owner='+info).success(function(data){
    packages.data = data;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In current situation you are assigning `$scope.packgs` to promise return by `$http.get` that why you are getting `$$state` in object(which is nothing but a promise object). Also you can not get the data returned by `PackageService.get` outside of `callback` function as you are expecting to get data using console.log($scope.packgs) in code(async operation will not work in synchronous way as you think).

The way you have implemented `packages.get` method, will never return a data as you are expecting there in controller method. But yes in `.success` of your `$http` call you are setting up that value in service `data` variable.

other than that you must have got error in your console, because you are trying `.success` method on promise returned by `PackageService.get` as promise doesn't have `.success` method in it.

```
PackageService.get($scope.currentUser()).then(function(data){
    $scope.packgs = PackageService.data; //assign data when ajax succeeded 
});
```

But rather I'd suggest you to do go for better approach than this

If you wanted to return data from `get` method of your `PackageService`, to return that from promise itself, but in that case you need to use `.then` instead of `.success`(callback don't have capability to return out data) will follow promise chain.

**Service**

```
packages.get = function(info){
  //used .then over $http.get to follow promise chain pattern

  return $http.get('/api/packages?owner='+info).then(function(response){
     packages.data = response.data;
     return data;
  });
  //or follow below one which is short and sweet
  //return $http.get('/api/packages?owner='+info);
};
```

**Controller**

```
PackageService.get($scope.currentUser()).then(function(response){
     $scope.packgs = response.data; //received data returned by promise
     console.log($scope.packgs); //console will give data out here only
});
```

Comment: Hey I am still getting an empty $scope.packgs i don't know whats the problem, is there anything else I can be doing wrong

Comment: You can't get console.log outside json ajax call..it should have been inside success callback..